# Ruby: Keeping track of Stock Transaction using Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, store

I am new to Ruby, and I am trying to code a "simple" system, so I can keep track of stock transaction. Calculating the average price, and in the future I will try to get dividends information.

So far, my code looks like this (PLEASE feel free to propose better ways to do my code, as I said, I am new).

```
require 'money'
require 'money/bank/google_currency'
require 'monetize'
require 'date'
require 'ystock'
require 'ostruct'

# (optional)
# set the seconds after than the current rates are automatically expired
# by default, they never expire
Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false #erro no formatting...
# set default bank to instance of GoogleCurrency
Money.default_bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new

class Stock

attr_accessor :code, :quantity, :price, :transactions, :spotprice

    def initialize(code:)
        @code = code
        @quantity =00
        @price = 00.to_money(:BRL)
        @transactions = []
        @spotprice = 0.to_money(:BRL)
    end    

    def spotprice
        begin
            asset_temp = Ystock.quote(@code.to_s + ".sa") # since it is South America.
            asset_info = OpenStruct.new asset_temp # organize it.
            @spotprice = asset_info.price.to_money(:BRL) # get the price. And transform it to Money, local currency
        rescue => @error #Is there an TCP/IP error?
            @spotprice = 0.to_money(:BRL)
        end
    end

    def buy (quantity:, price:, fees:, date:0)
        transactions.push type: "BUY", date: Date.strptime(date.to_s, '%d/%m/%Y'), quantity: quantity, price: price.to_money(:BRL), fees: fees.to_money(:BRL)
        #Lets calculate the average price that we bought:
        new_price = (((@quantity * @price.to_money(:BRL))) + ((quantity * price.to_money(:BRL)) + fees.to_money(:BRL))) / (@quantity + quantity)
        @quantity += quantity
        @price = new_price.to_money(:BRL) # new price is the average price.
    end

    def sell (quantity:,price:, fees:, date:)
        transactions.push type: "SELL", date: Date.strptime(date.to_s,     '%d/%m/%Y'), quantity: quantity, price: price.to_money(:BRL), fees:     fees.to_money(:BRL)
        @quantity -= quantity
    end
end
```

For example, I can create the asset, and make buys and sells:

```
ciel3 = Stock.new(code: "CIEL3")
ciel3.buy(quantity: 100, price: 9.00, fees: 21.5, date: "12/05/2015")
 p ciel3
ciel3.buy(quantity: 100,price: 12, fees: 21.7, date: "12/06/2015")
ciel3.sell(quantity: 50,price: 11.5,fees: 20.86, date: "20/06/2015")
p ciel3
ciel3.buy(quantity: 200,price: 15,fees: 23.6, date: "12/07/2015")
puts ciel3.price.format
puts
puts
# puts ciel3.spotprice.format
p ciel3.transactions
```

So far, it is OK (but I think that there is a cleaner and more readable way to do it... not sure).

But lets suppose I want to view all the transactions of the type "SELL".
How can I do this? How to look inside the ciel3.transaction array, that has the hash :type ??
Tnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a hash, you probably want a `Transaction` class.

If you back it with a DB and use ActiveRecord, then searching will be very simple.

If not, you can do `ciel3.transactions.select{|t| t[:type] == 'SELL'}`

Comment: B. Seven, thank you!! It is perfect. I don't know (yet) about the Transaction class. I will have a look. Would you give any other hint to my code?

Comment: I was not able to find the Transaction class for Ruby. Only for Rails, is it the same?

Comment: You would make your own `Transaction` class: `class Transaction`.

Comment: As far as other hints, I gather that you found this code. I think you can learn more by writing your own code. If you go through some Ruby tutorials, then it should be possible to write your own code to do this.

Comment: No, I haven't found this code. This was done by me. I will take this as a compliment! :D I just used ready codes (gems) to Money (so I will be able to convert it to USD, EUR, etc) and the gem to retrieve stock prices from Yahoo.
The class and methods was done by me.
I see, your suggestion to me is to write the Transaction class, and make it a subclass of ActiveRecord. So I can have it at DB. But this is for Rails only or for Ruby also? (Rails I have not yet started)
I am reading few books regarding Ruby. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use ActiveRecord without Rails. But, for what you are doing now, it might be simpler to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple command line inventory management app in Ruby. You can probably reuse a lot of code for your project.

It's on my GitHub: https://github.com/brunofacca/udacity-inventory-manager

Comment: "In the beginner's mind there are many possibilities, in the expert's mind there are few." ;-)